# Any example of Cast-Player-Sample ( google cast sdk example ) with the sample media library ( DRM )?

Tags: chromecast

I am looking for an example of an app that integrates the full ux example of google cast with the sample media library ( to be able to cast video with drm -> this library supports playready format ).

Have anyone any example ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The problem with creating samples like this is setting up the CORS header correctly.  If you use the Microsoft Playready sample files, with the correct CORS things will work.  SSW 720p H264 PLAYREADY (SuperSpeedWay, 720p, H264 AAC, with encryption) http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/  Note - Microsoft doesn't have a generic CORS header on all the content, so it won't work as is.

Comment: Yes, but i am looking for a code example to see how initialize the media player with the correct Protococol. Is the correct place create an instance of a Host with the url and the media element on the mediaReceiver.on_load and after that, pass this host to the protocol and create a player with the host and the protocol ?

Comment: The sample we have https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Media-Player-Library-Sample will do it for simple PlayReady files.  Where everything is in the Manifest.  When you need CustomData, or to specify your License server outside of the Manifest where things get a bit tricky.